# $\sqrt i$ representing two complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why does $$\sqrt i$$ represent two complex numbers in the argand plane?

$\sqrt i$  indicates an anticlockwise rotation by 45 degrees in the Argand plane from the initial x-direction. That way, it should represent a unique complex number. What's wrong with this?

Comment: If $a$ is your root with $a^2=i$, what about $-a$? Isn't $-a$ a complex number such that $(-a)^2=i$?

Comment: Yes, but what's wrong with the argand plane explanation?

Comment: What's wrong is that there's ambiguity between the *principal* square root of $i$, and the set of square roots of $i$.

Comment: Nice explanation can be found here:http://scimath.unl.edu/MIM/files/MATExamFiles/Lothrop%20MAT%20Paper.pdf

Comment: Considering root(i) in terms of rotation of a number 1 in the argand plane, it does represent only 1 complex no.

Comment: $\sqrt{a}$ represents two complex numbers for any $a\neq 0$ in argand plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is that nobody says that $\sqrt {\rm i}$ indicates an anticlockwise rotation. It can indicate a *clockwise* rotation equally well. Choosing it to be clockwise or anticlockwise is a *convention* that amounts to choosing the sign in front of the square root of $\rm i$.

Comment: I am not fully convinced by this argument. To get my point across how would it be modified to get  that $\sqrt[3]{i}$ has three values?

Comment: @quid: You are right, but it's not the answer to blame, but the question: in general, $z \mapsto \sqrt z$ is not a rotation of $45 ^\circ$, $z= \rm i$ is only  a very special case. No wonder, then, that the argument cannot be generalized. It's a nice trick, if you want - but not a false one! Note that the OP does not ask about $\sqrt \cdot$ having two branches, rather he phrases his question in very constraining terms of $45 ^\circ$ rotations and $\rm i$, thus establishing from the very beginning the terms in which he expects the answer to be given. I did my best given the circumstances.

Comment: Finding a square root of a complex number with absolute value $1$ in fact can always be thought of as halving an angle that corresponds to the original number, finding an $n$-th root as taking the $n$-th part of the angle. To find all the sqaure-roots or n-th roots one needs to consider all possible angles that would lead to the number. Thus, the in my opinion more to the point remark would be that $i$ (not its sqaureroot) is not only a 90 degrees anticlockwise rot.

Comment: While in case of squareroots it so happens that one can get by with "clockwise" and "counterclockwise,"  this is really a red-herring as one could also get by with saying $i$ is 90 and 450 deg anticlockwise. This approach would generalize.